# NSIntegers for Doubles in Swift

Tags: swift

I've been writing some code tonight to load data from the user's iPhone that has been saved previously.

Here's some of my code:

```
    var salesHighScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (salesHighScoreDefault.valueForKey("salesRecord") != nil) {
    salesRecord = salesHighScoreDefault.valueForKey("salesRecord") as! NSInteger!
    }


    var distanceWalkedHighScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (distanceWalkedHighScoreDefault.valueForKey("distanceWalked") != nil) {
        distanceWalkedRecord = distanceWalkedHighScoreDefault.valueForKey("distanceWalkedRecord") as! NS??????!
    }
```

Integer is to NSInteger! as Double is to _____________. (and no, it's not NSDouble! I've already tried that)

Comment: Use `NSNumber`, `NSNumber` provides readonly properties that return the object’s stored value converted to a particular Boolean, integer, unsigned integer, or floating point C scalar type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cast to `Double` directly, without `NS` prefix.

```
var integer: Int = 1

var double = Double(integer)

var nsnumber1 = NSNumber(integer: integer) as Double
```